# Do some skins influence gameplay?

Tags: league-of-legends

There was a similar post in year 12'. But I have to ask this question, because there are still some minor issues, that specific skins effect some pros. 
recently it came to my mind, that the new Vlad skin (some kind of toxic?) makes him appearing longer in his lake than the normal Vlad.  Another benefit would be the I-Blitzcrank, which has an opticial favor for the ownerside, concerning the hook ability. When I-Blitz hides in the grass you dont see the 'hook'.. 
I dont want to catalogue all of the skins I think they are imbalanced, because these may only be a persuasion on my part.

So, is this my psychological problem or can there really be skinbenefits, for example by rendering in game mechanicals?

Comment: I mentioned, that this is kind a duplicate - the "duplicate" is 2 years old, and in IT 2 years are ages.

Comment: For Arqade, it matters not.  If it's been asked before, then it's been asked before.  Indeed, it's that way for the whole of StackExchange.

Comment: @Flowdo We try to avoid duplicates as often as we can. If you feel like a question you've found is outdated you can join us in [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) to get help or answers. But it's a really good thing that you've done some research on the site first ;)

Comment: There's no need to downvote. It's true that this is a duplicate, but you will never know how the question is called (hence this one, it has all the words different but 'skins') until someone names it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is any potential differences between skins, giving or removing some benefits, they are unintended and could potentially be considered bugs. You could probably report the differences you see to Riot. They may deem some differences big enough to fix them.

Skins goal is only to be cosmetic changes to the champions, without providing any benefits or disadvantages, just changing the appearance, voice, sound and/or skill visual.

Comment: Skins with sunglasses reduce leona's damage to those targets. There's also an interaction between Zyra and Lumberjack Sion (which i'm not aware of). Some hidden passives are skin-specific. You're supposed to use knowledge and/or research to answer questions. If a person needs common sense, he can rely on his own.

Comment: He's talking about visual differences that could be game changing, or beneficial in some ways, not hidden bonuses.

Comment: We could argue that they should or not exists, true but I doubt it is intended to give any benefits other than the hidden bonuses. His example with Blitz grab is one I would consider a potential bug as if you don't see the grab coming as you do with the normal skin in some circumstance, this is an advantage that shouldn't be. Again, this is all arguable but skins shouldn't, IMO, give that kinda of "bonuses".

Comment: @You're on about whether they should or shouldn't be again, mate :p As I understand it, it's really about visual benefits - the small things that designers usually don't think about TOO much - such as how it's hard to see Commando Lux projectiles, or how Winter Annie's spells blend with the winter map (as said in the question this was a dupe to). Also, if you wanna argue, I'm up for it (somewhere else though), though if we think our "opinions" (which differ) are both right, we're paying attention to different variables, which is technically the flaw in any unstructured debate.

Comment: I remember seeing something about little league trundle being able to smack awau oriannas ball. I'm not 100% sure on it though. Other skins have more cosmetic/visual benefits, like user1337 stated. Another example is SGU. His autos and form transitions are a lot smoother on that skin versus his other ones. There is also a higher probability of getting invisible spears with headhunter nidalee (it was a prominent glitch a while back and I'm not sure if they patched it, I prefer bewitching anyways). There are no "official" bonuses other than looking awesome when trampling competition though.